# customizing the wordpress text color

Tags: css, wordpress

I am making my first steps learning to code. I made some ourses on Internet and now I decided to continue learning from the experience while I build a Wordpress Child Theme.

The thing is that I see that there are two ways to change the color of the text:

1) Using css

2) In the wordpress dashboard:

[image]

If I change the color of the text using css it will change again if I change it from the wordpress dashboard.

There are some pieces of text that I like to customize as I want using the wordpress dashboard, but there are some other pieces of text that I would like to write its color in css and make it unchangeable, even if I try to modify it in the wordpress dashboard.

Is there a way to make it?

I try to write `color: #000000 !important;` in my css but it doesn't work. Is there a way to change the color of a piece of text in css permanently?

Answer (score 1):

If you set the color via the WordPress Editor, it will of course also change the color with CSS. Let's assume you select a text in the editor and colorize it using clicking on one of the available colors, then the resulting HTML will include inline CSS. See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp
The only way to overwrite styles set like that is to set a style **!important** on the **same HTML element the inline CSS is applied to**.

Here an example: If you set the color of `body` by `!important` - the inline style of the inner DIV is still there. But if you uncomment the `.colorize` class it will overwrite the inline CSS color.

```css
body {
  color:orange!important;
}
/* uncomment this to overwrite the inline CSS
.colorize {
  color:yellow!important;
}
*/
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div>
    Content outer DIV
    <div class="colorize" style="color:blue;">
      Content inner DIV
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It should be mentioned that !important is what you should try to use as little as possible.
In your actual case you would usually change the WordPress editor so that no colors or only chosen ones are available to be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Using parent element class you can write style . It will take your child theme style.

```
<html>
<body class="home">
  <div class="main">
      <div class="colorize">
      Content inner DIV
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Parent theme :

```
<style>
.colorize{
    color:red;
}
</style>
```

child theme:

```
<style>
.main .colorize{
    color: green; //override using parent element class(main)
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Samyappa . But what is parent element class and how can I use it? I'm just starting to learn and there are some things that I don't know

Comment: Hi, @Valentin Verdegales  I have add details please follow if any doubt let me know.